# What is the list of Ignite Communication ephemeral port range?

Tags: spring, ignite

We have an active firewall on machines and Multiple Ignite Servers to increase availability but at the same time we can't keep open all the ports.
I have read multiple blogs and email on apache-ignite-users[[1](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Which-ports-does-ignite-cluster-need-to-run-normally-td8031.html)] to find out what ports are used between ignites nodes to establish and keepalive connections.

My Ignite Spring config

```java
@Bean
public Ignite igniteInstance(JdbcIpFinderDialect ipFinderDialect, DataSource dataSource) {
  IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
  cfg.setGridLogger(new Slf4jLogger());
  cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(0);
  TcpDiscoverySpi discoSpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi()
      .setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder(ipFinderDialect).setDataSource(dataSource)
          .setInitSchema(initialiseIgniteSchema))
          .setLocalPort(51000)
          .setLocalPortRange(100);
  cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoSpi);
  cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfigurations.toArray(new CacheConfiguration[0]));
  cfg.setFailureHandler(igniteFailureHandler);
  return Ignition.start(cfg);
}
```

this way I am specifying the discovery port[51000] and range[100] but when I run the `netstat` to see the connection on both the nodes but did notice the random ephemeral port range, what are these ports  [20353],[59856]  and is there a configurable option that I am missing to set the range?

`[user@machine ~]$  netstat -aon | grep 51000 | grep ES`

| header |  |  |  | h2 | h2 | h2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:51000 | 0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN | off (0.00/0/0) |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:59856 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host2:51000 | ESTABLISHED | off (0.00/0/0) |
| tcp | 0 | 0 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host1:51000 | XXX.XXX.XXX.host2:20352 | ESTABLISHED | keepalive (6007.95/0/0) |

**tl;dr**

1. I have 2 ignite server in the system which shares a cache
2. Due to Security implementation we have to close all the port unless used
3. Ignite server establishes a connection over a random ephemeral port range
4. Is there a way to restrict this range?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the port that Ignite uses to *listen* on. You've already changed the Discovery port. As a minimum, you'd also need to change the Communication SPI port (47100 by default) and possibly disable JMX (start with the `-nojmx` flag).

Using the default implementation, there's no way to configure the port of *outgoing* connections. That's a pretty unusual requirement. You could build your own Discovery SPI that binds to a specific port rather than zero -- that would require building on the default implementation and overriding the `TcpDiscoverySpi#createSocket()` method.